# Retrieving 1 row (sorted) per group + optimize speed SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables (using SQLite):

```
torrents
   infohash (unique, primary)
   etc...

dates
   date (e.g. 2019-10-09)
   infohash
   etc...
```

Each torrent is unique and has many dates (sometimes no dates yet).

I need to retrieve each `torrent` that has at least 1 `dates.date`, and sort them by their own most recent `dates.date` in descending order.

I am currently using:

```
SELECT
  torrents.infohash, dates.date
FROM
  torrents
LEFT JOIN 
  dates ON dates.infohash = torrents.infohash
WHERE 
  dates.date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY /* trying to get only 1 row per group */
  torrents.infohash
ORDER BY /* trying to get the most recent row per group */
  dates.date DESC
```

Problem 1: It fails as it gets the first date inserted only, and I need the latest date. The `ORDER BY` does nothing because `GROUP BY` is first.

Problem 2: It is slow. I have several million dates and the query is taking several minutes.

How can I fix Problem 1 and 2? Is there some index or temporary table I can use to make it faster?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the tables that are being used? [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) can tell you, and the sqlite3 shell's [.expert](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#index_recommendations_sqlite_expert_) command can suggest new ones. `dates(infohash)` is a likely option if not already indexed. Possibly `dates(infohash, date)`.

Comment: Also, primary key implies a unique key. There's no need to specify both like it sounds like you're doing.

Comment: I get this using @forpas solution`--EQP-- 0,0,0,SCAN TABLE torrents USING INDEX torrents_infohash_files
--EQP-- 0,1,1,SEARCH TABLE dates USING INDEX dates_infohash_date_peers (infohash=?)
--EQP-- 0,0,0,USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY` seems like ORDER BY is taking the most time. The first 2 are instant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT d.infohash, MAX(d.date)
FROM dates d
GROUP BY d.infohash
ORDER BY MAX(d.date) DESC;
```

Sometimes a correlated subquery can be faster (depending on how may dates there is per infohash.

```
SELECT td.*
FROM (SELECT t.infohash,
             (SELECT MAX(d.date)
              FROM dates d
              WHERE d.infohash = t.infohash
             ) date
      FROM torrents t
     ) td
WHERE date IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

For this to work well, you need an index on `dates(infohash, date)`.

Comment: That's super fast. How can I select all the torrents and dates extra fields using this method? I tried playing around with it but can't figure out how to add all the dates fields without errors. Also could you explain a bit how it works, I don't really understand it.

Comment: @user12341234 . . . That would be a different question.  In the second solution, it is simple to select all the columns from `torrents` -- just include them in the subquery.  If that doesn't help, then ask a new column.  Also, how much faster is this solution?

Comment: 5000ms vs 150000ms (2mil dates and 100k torrents). It's too bad I can't add the dates fields. I only use them for unit tests but I guess I will just turn off these tests for now.

Comment: is there a way to extract the sub queries into "functions", I find them very difficult to read/understand.

Comment: @user12341234 . . . (1) You can `join` back to the `dates` table to get the additional column.  With an index on `date`, this should be fast.  (2) No, SQLite doesn't support table values functions as far as I know.

Comment: thank you that actually worked and only added 5000ms to the speed

Comment: I'm actually still confused about what makes it so much quicker though. Could you explain?

Comment: @user12341234 . . . Using the index to fetch the maximum is much faster than aggregating all the data for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use a `LEFT JOIN`?
The condition in the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE dates.date IS NOT NULL
```

returns only the matching rows of the join, so why not an `INNER JOIN`?
Also, you do not do any aggregation to get the last date although you `GROUP BY torrents.infohash`.
So if you want the last date of each infohash change to this:

```
SELECT torrents.infohash, MAX(dates.date) lastdate
FROM torrents INNER JOIN dates 
ON dates.infohash = torrents.infohash
GROUP BY torrents.infohash
ORDER BY lastdate DESC
```

Finally an index on `dates.infohash` (if it does not exist) will help.

Comment: thanks it works, it does stall a bit at ORDER BY, `--EQP-- 0,0,0,SCAN TABLE torrents USING INDEX torrents_infohash_files
--EQP-- 0,1,1,SEARCH TABLE dates USING INDEX dates_infohash_date_peers (infohash=?)
--EQP-- 0,0,0,USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY`  do you know how to fix that?